# Paste from Excel master workbook to other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy/paste a range of cells from one workbook into all the other workbooks in the folder.

I have the code to open, close and save the files and to copy the range from the master.

How do I pasted the range into the other workbooks?

I tried the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088389/copy-paste-part-of-excel-workbook-to-workbooks-that-are-not-currently-open) question by Jim Simson and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686637/how-to-copy-from-master-workbook-and-paste-data-on-multiple-workbooks).

Code I wrote.

```vb
Sub COPYMASTERTODATA()
Dim myfolder As String
Dim myfile As String

'DEFINES FOLDER PATH
myfolder = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Desktop\DATA"

'DEFINES FILETYPE
myfile = Dir(myfolder & "\*xlsx")

Do While myfile <> ""

'OPENS ALL FILES IN FOLDER
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & "\" & myfile

'COPIES RANGE OF CELLS IN MASTER
Workbooks("MASTER.XLSM").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E30").Copy

'PASTES RANGE TO OTHER WORKBOOK
Workbooks("myfile").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue

'CLOSES ALL FILES
Workbooks(myfile).Close Savechanges = True

myfile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I tried different methods to paste the range into either all the workbooks or just one workbook. The macro opens, saves and closes the workbooks but no pasting happens.

Comment: Your code, as provided, doesn't contain any instructions for pasting. Please update your code to show what you have tried regarding pasting

Comment: Besides what's commented above, try to copy after openning the other fille, I think openning a file cancels the copy action. open->copy->paste->close and lose the `_` at the end of the copy sentence.

Comment: Added tried code for pasting.

Comment: Why ' Workbooks("DATA1.xlsx")' and not 'Workbooks(myfile)'

Comment: That was the code i used for trying to paste to that specific workbook. I have also tried with myfile but the result is the same.

Comment: Edited code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Data_To_All_SubFiles()
    
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FileDir As String
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim ofolder As Object
    
    Dim TargetWB As Workbook
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FileDir = "C:\Users\cameron\Documents\temp"
    Set ofolder = FSO.getfolder(FileDir)
    
    For Each oFile In ofolder.Files
        If FSO.getextensionname(oFile) = "xlsx" Then
            Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Name)
            
            ' >>> Use this to copy
            Sheet1.Range("B2:C5").Copy
            TargetWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:C5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
            ' *** OR use this to copy
            'TargetWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:C5").value = Sheet1.Range("B2:C5").value
            
            TargetWB.Save
            TargetWB.Close
            
        End If
    Next oFile
    
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just update what ranges you want copied, what XL type you want to target, the target folder... whatever else.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works very well, as all i did was insert the filepath to the folder to = filedir. Does it target the workbook that is currently open? Or can you set it to only copy from a specific file in the folder?

Comment: It targets the workbook the code is saved inside. If you want to target another workbook, you'll need to replace sheet1 with workbooks("yourworkbookname.xlsm"). worksheets("name of the desired worksheet")

Comment: The code gives me a run time error 1004, saying that the destination files may have been moved, but they have not. Can you help in any way?

Comment: What line does it error on?

Comment: I press F8 to debug until i get to the line starting with "Set TargetWB":
`For Each oFile In ofolder.Files
        If FSO.getextensionname(oFile) = "xlsx" Then
Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Name)`

Comment: Try workbooks.open(ofile.path).

Comment: It seems to work. I will try to test it out some more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Cameron.

Is it possible to include multiple ranges? For example like below

`TargetWB.Worksheets(1).Range("AXX:BXX").Value = Sheet1.Range("AXX:OXX").Value

TargetWB.Worksheets(1).Range("CXX:DXX").Value = Sheet1.Range("CXX:DXX").Value`

Doing so seems to work but it also gives desync errors on sheets on a onedrive.

Comment: Hm, I've run into these kinds of issues working with files on onedrive, unfortunately, I've never solved them.

Comment: Hm, I will see if i can fix it somehow.  I will let you know if i find a solution.

Comment: Ive tried to have it copy the ranges sequentially rather than concurrently with some mildly improved results. Its running the same code twice but with the different ranges. Do you think its possible to write something like this but do it smarter? See below comment for code.

Comment: `For Each oFile In ofolder.Files
        If FSO.getextensionname(oFile) = "xlsx" Then
            Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            
            TargetWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:E2").Value = Sheet1.Range("B2:E2").Value
                        
            TargetWB.Save
            TargetWB.Close
            
        End If
    Next oFile`

So running this twice with a different range the second time.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why that would help...